# Django 2.1.1 not found on beanstalk t2.micro ec2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I created a python virtualenv on my local ubuntu machine just as advised in official aws beanstalk documentation [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-django.html). Installed Django Then `pip freeze > requirements.txt` . My requirements.txt file has Django==2.1.1

When I `eb deploy` i get health green status ready. But when I ssh into ec2  and check packages list

```
eb ssh
pip freeze
```

I dont see Django at all.
Then I tried to manually install django:

```
pip install django
```

It installed `Django==1.11.20` So i think beanstalk aws ec2 doesnt have the Django version mentioned in requirements.txt and so pip never installed it. Is that right?
If so do we have to manually install packages with correct version everytime when we use beanstalk

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Elastic Beanstalk uses requirements.txt to determine which package to install on the EC2 instances that run your application. Hence, having just 'Django==2.1.1' in requirements.txt would not install it on the instance.

In order to install this package, further you need to follow the below steps:

1. Create a new directory, called .ebextensions in the root directory of your package.

> Note: “.ebextensions” folder in the root of the package directory is
>   used to configure Elastic Beanstalk instances. The files in this
>   folder are using .config extension, with the YAML code inside it and
>   are read in alphabetical order so that they can run in a specific
>   order for various configuration's deployment on instances.

2. Within the .ebextensions directory, add a configuration file named django.config with the following text:

Example ~/your_application_name/.ebextensions/django.config

```
option_settings:
 aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:
  WSGIPath: your_application_name/wsgi.py
```

This setting, WSGIPath, specifies the location of the WSGI script that Elastic Beanstalk uses to start your application.

3. That's it. Now, deploy your EB application and check if the Django is installed.

Comment: Yes I followed everything mentioned in official aws beanstalk guide which included steps you mentioned in your answer. But it did not work.

Comment: Ok. May I know the version of python installed on your server? I think it is related to compatibility issues of python version with django's.